# CodeIgniter 1.7 Authentication Library

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter

I'm trying to find an authentication library for CodeIgniter 1.7.x, but am not having much luck. I originally found this stack**overflow** post: [How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best), which listed several, but most were either too simple and/or were designed for CodeIgniter 1.5.x

I've played with FreakAuth, UserAuth, Redux, and several others, but had issues getting any of them to properly work. Does anyone know of a good library to use with CodeIgniter 1.7.x?

Comment: I'm looking too.  There doesn't seem to be one that's super great for 1.7...not that I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [DX Auth](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/98465/)? It's very full featured and works with 1.7 (says so in the post, and I have personally used it).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the simplest Authentication library a few months ago, and I found 'The Authentication Library'. It is very easy to use, the author has a CI-User_guide-type for help, and it doesn't have any of the bloat I've found in other auth libraries.

You can find it here:
http://programmersvoice.com/codeigniter/the-authentication-library-1-0-6

The author is very responsive on the CI boards and on his facebook/twitter page for comments and assistance. Try it out, I've had success with it in my 1.7 apps.

Answer (score 1):

In case any one else finds this thread the best, and easiest authentication library I have found so far is [TankAuth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/). Super easy to install and comes with all the basic auth examples (login, logout, remember me, forgotten password etc).

Edit - apparently Tank_auth was created in response to a list of requirements on another discussion here about what an auth library should do, so doubly worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

[Ion Auth](http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) is currently one of the more attractive options. It's lean, widely used, actively maintained and has a good feature set.

Answer (score 0):

Redux 2 beta is built for 1.7 however obviously, it is still in beta.

There is a large discussion on this topic here:

[How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best)

Comment: Quite obviously.  I've tried to use it, but it ended up frustrating me too much to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully tested Redux2 Beta on a CI 1.7 smallish project. No issues and the code was very easy to understand (needed no further documentation). I'm looking forward for the final release.