# PHP login class

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, login-script, user-roles

I'm looking for a good **PHP login class** via MySQL, and I'm not yet completely satisfied with anything I've found. This [prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686185/best-starting-point-for-a-website-with-user-management-functionality) doesn't really address my needs, as I'd prefer to stay away from PEAR and CodeIgniter, and just have a simple and small PHP class to do the job.

There's a [TalkPHP forum](http://www.talkphp.com/script-giveaway/?daysprune=-1&order=desc&sort=views) that has several to choose from, but they all seem to have something or other lacking.

- [PHP Login Class](http://www.talkphp.com/script-giveaway/1364-php-login-class.html) by **daz**: seems a little tricky to extend, and doesn't support multiple user roles
- [TalkPHP.com_Login_Script.PHP5.Beta_1](http://www.talkphp.com/script-giveaway/1879-easy-modify-login-script-hierarchical-user-permissions-xml-account-file.html) by **Wildhoney**: looks very extensible, supports configurable user roles, but no db support and stores passwords in plaintext in an XML file!
- [authclass](http://www.talkphp.com/script-giveaway/1056-secure-login-script.html) by **Sam Granger**: again, no support for multiple user roles, but does use MySQL

Now, my first instinct was to just dive in a re-code the last one in that list (authclass), but fortunately, my second instinct was to *ask stackoverflow* :)

So here's the big question: is there a **secure**, **open source**, **multiple-user-role** login class for **PHP5** and **MySQL** that anyone is using? Thanks in advance, and I appreciate any kind of comments here, even if you don't have a particular piece of code to point to!

Comment: This Q might be old, but is still very relevant. I can recommend http://php-login.net for this. No role support, but you could implement that with a simple new db column and a slightly modified registration process.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html):

> `Zend_Auth` is concerned only with
>   authentication  and not with
>   authorization. Authentication is
>   loosely defined as determining whether
>   an entity actually is what it purports
>   to be (i.e., identification), based on
>   some set of credentials.
>   Authorization, the process of deciding
>   whether to allow an entity access to,
>   or to perform operations upon, other
>   entities is outside the scope of
>   `Zend_Auth`.

For a multiple-user-role (authorization) implementation take a look at [`Zend_Acl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html):

> Zend_Acl provides a lightweight and
>   flexible access control list (ACL)
>   implementation for privileges
>   management. In general, an application
>   may utilize such ACL's to control
>   access to certain protected objects by
>   other requesting objects.

Please keep in mind that it's possible to make use of those without having to commit to using the entire [Zend_Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), as it's not a full-stack framework, and I'm in no way trying to encourage you to use the above, or any framework for that matter. Just thought I would mention those as they haven't been already.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you don't have to use the whole thing. (And another +1 if I could for not just answering "you should use the blahblahblah framework!"

Comment: this looks very promising! thanks karim79 - i'm doc surfing as we speak :)

Comment: these look perfect - thanks for the suggestion. easy to get up & running, too!

Comment: i should also note for anyone reading this question in the future, both these libraries come in the "minimal" zend framework download - you don't need to download the big package (but at time of writing, Zend still forces you to register before downloading).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look into how Drupal handles their log-in service.  I'm quite fond of that whole message board setup - you may be able to take some of their ideas and make your own class

Comment: Wow! I admit I hadn't considered using a web service for the task. I'll have to chew on that one for a bit ... thx PSU_Kardi :)