# Control user access for different folders on web

Tags: php

I've been looking for a small program/script to run on Apache that can manage user access to several folders on my website. The issue is that it's not one block of content that will require "member" status but several different folders. User 1 may have access to folder A, but not B and user 2 maybe both folders or only B.

Looking for a program that makes it easy to manage these issues for a few hundred users. It doesn't require strong passwords, just confirmation of e-mail address once. Preferably in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) and this:

[PHP login class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070491/php-login-class/)

Comment: thanks, but I'm not a programmer enough to create at program of my own and use the library. Was hoping someone had already done that.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for [here](http://vibralogix.com/sitelokpw/). Have not installed yet, but documentation is good and interface looks fine.