# Make server directory inaccessible to all external connections

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm creating a very simple login system where my php code stores and reads file names(account name) and content(password) but anyone could simply just navigate to that folder and read whatever. so what i want is that a folder gets "locked" from any connections, and still read / write to it with php. i use xampp to host, if it has any relevance

is this possible? if not, are there other simple ways of storing / reading account password and name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Control user access for different folders on web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085842/control-user-access-for-different-folders-on-web)

Comment: unfortunately no, sitelok would've been great if i had the budget, but this is more a personal project, of learning website development more. and "Zend_auth" is now "mezzio" and seems a bit too complicated for my level of knowledge. i'm looking for a simple one, preferely with php/javascript code or something else located in apache / xampp. sorry, thanks for your comment though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my solution, by putting

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

inside `.htaccess` in the folder i want private