# Php codeigniter - simpleloginsecure

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter

Has anybody tried out simpleloginsecure authentication library for codeigniter?  I like that it has such a small footprint.  Also it uses [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for hashing which is supposed to be good.  I am concerned that it does not store session data in the database (i.e. `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;`).  I guess I could add custom functionality.  But if the hashing is secure is it still important to validate session data or is it ok not to store it in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure simpleloginsecure is secure enough for production use for most smaller applications. This has become the authoritative post on Codeigniter authentication libraries.. it has a rundown of all the pros-cons of the major libraries, including simpleloginsecure:

[How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best/476902#476902)

**Update:** Also, zend-auth (courtesy of the zend framework) is supposed to be very good, and can be integrated into Codeigniter. I am working on integrating it myself for one of my side projects:
http://freakauth.4webby.com/tutorials/using-zend-framework-components-in-code-igniter

Comment: I used that tutorial to integrate Zend Auth with CI 1.7.1 just last week.  Worked without any real hitches; been using it in Dev without any problems.  Haven't tested it in the real world yet.

Answer (score 0):

Provided there are no glaring SQL injection vulnerabilities, and the passwords are salted before encyption, I wouldn't hesitate to use the library.

Sessions on the filesystem is only really a problem if you are running your application on multiple servers. You can extend PHP's inbuilt session handler to use the database, anyway.