# Codeigniter admin/auth system?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm starting a new project with codeigniter, and I'd like to start on a system that's already built so I can reduce the time of development.

Is there a good system that handles user authentication along with an admin interface to manage users that can be easily expanded to a web-app?

**If this is too vague, I can expand**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread here appears to have some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best)

But the question was more about libraries. Either way, implementing some of the things on that thread would save you time.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for is a Content Management System (CMS).

There are a few ones out there that use Codeigniter as a framework for their CMS.

Edit:  Even if you can't find a boilerplate CMS that you like, you can google about CMS's to design a simple one of your own as there's LOTS of tutorials and information about requirements and such when you know the term CMS.

Comment: The way you asked the question made me assume your intelligence level on the subject matter was quite low, hence my general response.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Redux Auth](http://code.google.com/p/reduxauth/) for CodeIgniter.  It comes with an example implementation, and can easily be used to manage user authentication for your CodeIgniter site.  I just implemented Beta2 with the latest version of CodeIgniter, so while it's not actively updated, it still works with the latest build.

Comment: Redux Auth is dead, use the spin-off Ion Auth instead. It's been drastically improved and is the most used system in CI. http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com/) as default admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started looking into [Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com/):

> Bonfire helps you build CodeIgniter-based PHP web applications even faster, by providing powerful tools and a beautiful interface you won't be ashamed to show your client.
>
> - Ready to customize Admin Interface.
> - User Management with Role-Based Access Control.
> - Fully Modular codebase.
> - Built around HMVC.
> - Database backup, migration, and maintenance.
> - Powerful, parent/child capable theme engine.
> - Simple Email Queue to keep your ISP happy.
> - UI-based module builder.

Looks good at first glance!