# Fastest / Easiest method to develop a multi-user gaming engine in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, yii, kohana

I'm an advanced designer, but also starting out a career in development: I'm a PHP intermediate user. I (unfortunately) learnt procedural development, and not OOP.

My current project is a multi-user game web-app and I was developing procedurally only for my Boss to insist that it has to be OOP, so I needed to start learning OOP (I believe I am a relatively fast learner). A friend advised me to just learn a lightweight PHP framework and move on from there, since the project must be launched in less than three weeks (I have roughly 2 weeks left now)!

After viewing a lot of articles comparing them, I ended up with CodeIgniter, Kohana, and Yii based on the efficiency and the lightweight-edness. I am not quite used to command-line instructions like it's done in Yii, so I had to drop it off to save my time :(. Kohana looks very interesting, but I am new to the PHP5 and OOP it uses and there's VERY LITTLE help on Kohana, I even tried to buy books but there are none. CodeIgniter has a lot of helpful material, but it has no official Authentication module with Access Control, and the three open-source modules I have tested did not integrate well with other modules I am using.

Please can anyone recommend another OOP PHP framework with a quick learning curve, or provide some pointers to resolve the problems I had with those 3 frameworks tested, or should I just develop the entire application out of the box after studying OOP extensively? Thanks for your time.

Comment: PHP for something that sounds like a MMORPG? Impossible deadlines? The main developer with no php or OOP experience? argh

Comment: @Koper: No, its not like MMORPG, it just has to do with using forms and fetching simple data from a MySQL database to compare each user's game-play with expected data in the DB. You can relate that to an multichoice online examination or something. What do you suggest, please?

Comment: oh, i misunderstood then, sorry!

Comment: If you are already using other modules, then you should give a hint of what type of code they are. You ask for a lightweight framework, which would mean a framework with few classes / functions (but still have ACL classes). If the framework must be useful, then it should have the necessary functions / classes; the more functions / classes the framework has, the less code you need to write (in an ideal world).

Comment: Good luck doing HP/MP refresh intervals in PHP :)

Answer (score 2):

There are frameworks, that provide an authentication natively but there is no way, that you can learn those in two weeks AND finish your project.

CodeIgniter was the first framework I learned and it was the perfect choice for me: The documentation is really good: reading the documentation enabled me to fully understand the MVC pattern. If I was in your position I would definitely use codeigniter and integrate one of the many free authentication plugins discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best).

After you finished your project, you can go on and start learning symfony and Zend Framework, depending on your preferences.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am checking out those 3rd party modules right now. About CodeIgniter, do you think I can learn it with no knowledge of OOP, or I need to study PHP 5 (OOP) first of all?

Comment: I think you can dive right into the codeigniter documentation. Codeigniter is not very "religious" about OOP: It uses it, where it makes good sense (with models for example) and describes what it does in the documentation. As far as I know, it does not use "advanced" PHP5 concepts (like reflection) so you do not have to understand them in order to use codeigniter.