# What's the best library for User Registration / Authentication / Management for CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I know there's no "best" and it all depends on HOW you use it, but please let me know your experiences with the different ones.

Thanks.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best and a few others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used Tank Auth like suggested by Sarfraz and it worked fine. 
I tried 2 other libs before that without much success. The only thing that it doesn't have is an admin to manage user, but it wasn't required in my case.

Answer (score 7):

I have been working with (and on) [Ion Auth](http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) for a few weeks now and it is not only lightweight but incredibly simple.

It is based on the very popular Redux Auth 2 BETA and has been given a serious overhaul as some of that code was... well just really bad.

Documentation is coming soon, but basically just look at the library and the provided example controller and you can't go far wrong.

Comment: Hey, thanks for mentioning Redux. I created it some years ago and I agree with your statement. Back then I was young and in-experienced and it still baffles to this day why people praise it like it's the best. I've since moved onto Kohana, but it's great it's been forked into something more substantial. Good work, sir.

Comment: Thank you for not taking offense. Looking over some of my own code from a year or two ago I end up feeling rather ill. TBH I never used Redux Auth but I think its praised for being very lightweight. Compare it to FreakAuth Light and its a MASSIVE improvement. Good luck with your Kohana antics.

Comment: Is Ion Auth fully functioning already or still under development?

Comment: I'm using it in a live app and haven't had any problems. It's been released but neither me or Ben can be bothered writing documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to go for the [Tank Auth](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/). It is good and always concurrent with codeigniter.