# resusable function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, code-reuse, helper

Almost in all function in most of my controller i have to see to same things. i.e

> 1.Check if logged in. 
>   2.Check the privilege.

I know how to do it. But what is the best way, so that i don't have to re-write the same
code everywhere? Is it to make a helper or something? I'm a bit new to codeigniter, all i know is basic php!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the methods in your controller need the same code, you can put that authentification code in the constructor.

Otherwise, creating a helper is probably the best way, but you'll still have to repeat the function in each method subject to authentification.

Answer (score 0):

You may find these links useful:

[What Code Igniter authentication library is best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best)
[Authentication with CodeIgniter](http://davidwinter.me.uk/articles/2009/02/21/authentication-with-codeigniter/)

You might want to actually create a ***helper class*** for user handling to avoid repetitive code if you want.