# CodeIgniter authentication, permissions and admin system, or any other PHP equivilant of Django?

Tags: php, django, authentication, cakephp, codeigniter

Reading all about PHP frameworks, CodeIgniter seems really nice in that I like it's speed and raw PHP-ness, but it really misses features that CakePHP has (ACLs, authentication,etc.). I originally thought that it would be ok to write the stuff i needed myself (and CodeIgnitier is definitely the DIY tool), but I'm really missing out on a pre-made thing like that. Is there a PHP-equivilant of Django, but not that extreme, like that provides an admin panel and some automagicness, but is still "flat-packed" and doesn't require command line like CodeIgniter does?

Or does anybody know a *good* module for CodeIgniter to add (1) an admin panel, (2) a login system and (3) a permissions system?

Or should I just shut up and write my own? (I was avoiding this not really because of effort but I'm not sure that I'll write it securely enough or use proper conventions)

**Update:** Or should I try and modify a pre-build CMS like PyroCMS to my needs as that is already has built-in authentication and permissions and admin panel, but might be unstable?

Comment: Write your own. Having just rewritten CodeIgniter for security reasons (don't ask) you shouldn't worry about your thing being any less secure than CI already is. Seriously. -- Also, I am currently building a new framework that takes security into account. However it won't do what you want either. But I should mention that I am working on competition for CI.

Comment: You should consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-code-igniter-authentication-library-is-best before writing your own Auth / permissions system.

Comment: I would just "shut up and write my own".. ;) The session library is really powerful, and with the right understanding of your goal's... ACL's and login stuff is pretty simple.

Comment: To raise the chance people will help you, it's advised to accept some answers of your previous questions first.

Comment: Or should I try and modify a pre-build CMS like PyroCMS to my needs as that is already has built-in authentication and permissions and admin panel, but might be unstable? Writing my own does look the like best so far but also the most effort, are there any other frameworks/programs requiring less effort for these sort of things? Primariliary, I'm looking for stability and extendability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And ther is also [BackendPro](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/BackendPro) for Codeigniter. I haven't tried it but seem like it does what you want here ...

Other than that you can try [TankAuth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) or [Erkana](http://www.michaelwales.com/2010/02/protecting-controllers-with-erkanaauth/) for auth and [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) for ACL they are pretty simple to use :)

Comment: +1 For Zend_Acl, though you could also consider using the complete Zend Framework instead of CI :p.

Comment: @wimvds: of course you could do everything with Yend Framework, but question was "auth for Codeigniter..." :))

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter is a basic framework which is why I love it. It does not provide Authentication, Authorization or Access Control because they are so generic it is incredibly difficult to make one that is very very easy to use.

If you would like to use a really simple authentication system try [Ion Auth](http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) (the one used in PyroCMS) which works for the majority of situations but not all.

I think Django and Rails are doing a great job but both are going beyond what a normal framework is. CodeIgniter gives you enough space to code in your own conventions are greats ways of doing things instead of forcing you to spend ages working out the developers conventions instead.

Give it a go and look over PyroCMS for examples of how to use Ion Auth. As the Lead Developer of Pyro I can tell you that v1.0.2 is pretty stable. :)

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous PHP frameworks that have their built-in Authentication:

1. CakePHP
2. Kohana
3. Yii Framework