# Is PEAR Auth really a viable option for PHP authentication?

Tags: php, pear, authentication

Looking at [How can I store my users' passwords safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/help-me-make-my-password-storage-safe), the best way to encrypt passwords is using phpass. I want to use PEAR Auth package for authentication, but PEAR only supports md5, sha1, sha256, sha512 and PEAR doesn't add a salt to the hash.

PEAR Auth also doesn't support many of the features that are listed in [How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-codeigniter-authentication-library-is-best/476902#476902)

- reCAPTCHA supported
- Activation emails
- Unactivated accounts auto-expire
- Uses phpass for hashing (and also hashes autologin codes in the DB)
- Very reasonable security model around failed login attempts (good protection against bots and DoS attacks)
- "Remember me" functionality

My question is: is PEAR Auth really a viable choice? It seems to use it, I will have to write all the missing features myself. **Is there a better, more feature-rich Auth library that is not wrapped inside a framework**? I just want basic, secure authentication for my simple web app.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, however sha256 and sha512 are good for hashing if you are using rounds and a random salt. I suggest you look into [crypt](http://php.net/crypt). I'm not sure if PEAR Auth supports it, but if it does, you can use that instead of another library.

Comment: As @mike suggested, sha could work. PEAR is a viable auth library, it just isn't as feature rich as I think most basic web apps need; i.e., it is missing these features: lost password, remember me, activation emails.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth which is both framework-agnostic and database-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its only about the password hashing, I'd recommend using [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).
How you can use it in PHP is already a topic of a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/help-me-make-my-password-storage-safe).

Comment: It's partly the hashing, partly the missing features. Perhaps the best solution is to use Tank Auth (recommend here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-codeigniter-authentication-library-is-best/476902#476902) but rewrite it to work without CodeIgniter.