# User Management in CodeIgniter 2.1.0

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, user-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter)

What is the best library for User Registration / Authentication / Management for CodeIgniter 2.1.0?

Thanks!!

Comment: Check out this great thread: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-codeigniter-authentication-library-is-best

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Tank Auth](https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth) and [IonAuth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) are both great for all of the above in my opinion. Each has their own pros and cons. Most notably for you will be the documentation. IonAuth is [heavily documented](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/), and well commented throughout. Tank Auth is [lightly documented](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/), and is very well commented throughout. I personally prefer IonAuth, and have used it in several projects. If you want some additional modifications to make it even easier to work with, then check out this article [here](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion [IonAuth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) for user registration and authentification and [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) for authorization (Access Control List).

Answer (score 0):

Thats your choice dude, If you take an ORM approach neither IONAuth nor TANK will suffice.
Choose a database structure throughout your project's then decide, If that means a custom Auth lib, then so be it....

Comment: I hear what @Phillip is saying; if Tank Auth & IonAuth are bound to the native CI Active Record system, that's a bit of a shame.  Need to dig in a bit, but really looking for something that offers some interfaces and controllers whereby an implementation via Propel or some other ORM was straightforward.