# what is the simple configuration,complete user guide but strong Authentication library in Codeigniter2

Tags: authentication, codeigniter-2

i've read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-codeigniter-authentication-library-is-best) about authentication library. some of this answer is not satisfy me. my qeustion is:

1. i know some of the libraries above has not been maintenance
   anymore/compatible with Codeigniter 2.0 . but which one who still be
   maintenanced ? some of them doesnt have any documentation (tank_auth) would u like to show me the complete documentation instead of basic information founded in the [konyukhov's](http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) site ?
2. I  plan to make a -[dooid](http://www.dooid.com)-like web or a-[identy](http://www.identyme.com)-like web for
   my local colleges.

   what is the most suitable authentication for my case?.

   i mean it is simple, clear and complete user_guide ,compatible with
   codeigniter 2.0 but strong.

excuse me with my english. i am indonesian and i cant speak english well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great luck and would highly recommend [Tank Auth](https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth).

It requires only a bit of setup and provides several built in functions for checking if a person is logged in and other useful authentication functions.  It's fairly well documented and there's a good community of developers to help if you get stuck.

Comment: ok , can you give me a link contains an example of building a website with tank_auth library? i want another example besides the example included in the package. :D. a much more example a much i can learn :D

Comment: Google should be able to find you some tutorials. Here's one that goes through setting it up - http://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/setting-up-tank-auth-2/