# Login System with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I am new to codeigniter but i am very clear with the basics. I am starting with my new web application (a CMS) actually.

I want to know the best methodology used to create a login system with codeigniter for admin panel (backend).

Regards,
Mrinal Purohit

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know about the libraries available for login/logout and more than you should read this:

[How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/what-codeigniter-authentication-library-is-best)

and if you just simply want to understand a secure & simple login process then you should go and read the code for this one:

https://github.com/DaBourz/SimpleLoginSecure

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend ion auth: http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

it has great documentation, you could have several types for users,
and that you could easily have admin group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tank_auth: http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/
It's very easy to use!

Answer (score 2):

Here another library :)
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/forums/viewthread/229645/
Best regards.