# Codeigniter - User Authentication/login plugin/class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, authorization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter)

anyone here used a user login/registration class for Codeigniter? I've looked everywhere and there doesn't seem to be a 'go to' class that isn't only in the early stages of development (not very mature)

anyone know any to recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

I have use it in all my last CI projects. So I recommend it.

Besides it is the basis for the register/authentication processes in the `users` module of [pyrocms](https://www.pyrocms.com/),  a "going up" CI-based CMS. So it will count with support for long time...