# CodeIgniter authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter)

One interesting thing that I would like to know CodeIgniter doesn't have any build in authentication system.

Can anyone tell me if there is any existing plugin for that? If they have, any recommendation for those plugin?

Comment: you must also look my libary Aauth  

https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many authentication libraries. You can create your own too.

Find of few authentication libraries here: http://blog.pisyek.com/2011/11/5-best-authentication-libraries-for-codeigniter/

Ion Auth is quite popular.