# User Roles in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, user-roles

I wanna make a User Roles based on payments. I have seen exact system in the website www.indiancupid.com`. There when you register, you become a standard member, you can see the profiles of other users but you can't contact them until you pay, and when you pay from your Credit Card, you become a gold member. Being a Gold member you can send messages and can chat directly with online members. When the time (for which you upgraded to gold member) finishes, you automatically become a standard member again.

I wanna make this type of user roles system using CodeIgniter.

Would anyone suggest me any library which can do it for me?

Thank You.

Comment: you can't ask people here to do your code. show us what have you tried and then we can help.

Comment: to be fair, he's not. He's asking for a library where the code has already been done for him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, You have described the way almost every dating/subscription website works.

There are so many questions about authentication systems for codeigniter, check this out for example:

[How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter)

I have only used ion auth - http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/ and tanks auth - http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/, these seem to be the most popular with the biggest user bases. Both can be easily modified to have different levels of user access. In fact ion has this out of the box you just have to put in your own group checks.
Personally I would build off the back of ion auth. Ion auth is a good lib which has only the basics, allowing you to set things up however you want. It is also in my opinion the easiest to work into an existing application due to it's minimal nature

However if you are looking for something which is going to come ready made, you could look at ezauth - http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/70386/. I seem to remember this access levels and an admin panel going on. Unfortunately the demos gone (never a good sign) and you may find it difficult to make changes to if it doesnt work exactly the way you want.