# how to use usercake in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, usercake

I need to embed/use the [`Usercake`](http://usercake.com/) idea in Codeigniter? How should I go about doing this?

I am trying to use the `userlogin`, `session`, etc classes of UserCake in CI, but not having much luck.

Can anybody help me to do this? I have tried to search the solution in usercake official site, and came across [this thread](http://usercake.com/thread.php?id=71), but I am still unable to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use two different frameworks. My suggestion would be to use one of the available CodeIgniter libraries to manage your users. Refer to [How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter) for more information.