# codeigniter custom session table fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies

I want to know if there is any way to define custom fields in the sessions table of CodeIgniter.

By default, CodeIgniter stores session values in the following fields:

```
`session_id`, 
`ip_address`, 
`user_agent`, 
`last_activity`, 
`user_data`
```

What if I want to store a little more information in the sessions table using cookies? I mean, if I want to add `username`
and want to change the field name `session_id` to `SessionID`.

Is it possible to achieve that without too much effort??

Comment: everything that you store with `$this->session->set_userdata('key','value');` goes into the `user_data` column, so there is nothing else you have to do. as for `SessionID` instead of `session_id` you'll have to override the CI_Session class with your own.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish would be better served with an authentication library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

You can use set_userdata() function

like this

```
    $newdata = array(
                'username'  => 'sudz',
               'email'     => 'sudz@some-site.com'                 
           );

    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

you can't change session_id its used by codeigniter, instead you can define your own session_id with defferent name. or you have to override the CI_Session class.