# How many controllers should i have for login & registration

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, registration

this is rather a conceptual question. I am developing a registration + login system in Codeigniter.

Currently i have a user controller, which would take care of the user's profile and post's related to the user. Well i am confused if I should include the registration and login function inside the user controller or should i have them as standalone controllers with their associated model and view ofcourse?

There is no code to show here, just wanted to know the best practice.

Comment: Depends upon you and your preference. It's logical in a way to use a different controller as it will show a separate `url` to the user like `site.com/login` and a related model.

Comment: there is a standard, use libraries that are already build (why developing things that are already there for free), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other's answers, there is no standard, you have to follow your personal standard, at your liking.
Usually i create a single controller called `Auth.php`
Don't know if it's the best practice but as you can see it will be readable :

```
class Auth{

function signup(){

}
function login(){

}
function logout(){

}
function recover_password(){

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no best practice, just do where you believe in. There are no standards for things like that.

I believe in seperated components so i should create standalone controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule that dictates how you must organize your code.
However here is what i consider "best practice":

**As far as possible, one controller should 'map' to one page.**

So 'user page' should have a 'user controller', 'sign in page' a 'sign in controller', 'registration page' a 'registration controller', and so on...

Nothing is stopping us from using one single php files with 10,000 lines for our program, but i think most would agree that the problem with doing that is that maintaining such a code base which be a nightmare.

When you later decide to change the registration page like add a new field, do you want to have to look at a file that contains the user and sign in code logic that you aren't interested in or a file with only what you are concerned with?

What if you had to tell another developer to do it? image this... "help me add a field to the registration form, you will need to look in the user controller and scroll down to the 3 function that is the registration form logic" vs. "help me add a field to the registration form, just look at the registration controller"

I leave you with a quote by Martin Golding

> *Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath*

Comment: ... well, he has chosen to use CodeIgniter. It comes with built-in psychopath threat.