# Secure my API using oauth 2 build under codeigniter framework

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, oauth

I need to build my own API and i need to secure my API Using Oauth 2  server i Have try many ways to integrate Oauth 2 for the codeigniter as library but its not working there is errors how to integrate oauth server with codeigniter to secure my API any library ? plugin ? helpers?

http://oauth.net/2/

I m trying to use this https://github.com/fkooman/php-oauth

How can i use those files inside Codeigniter

Comment: I think you should grab CodeIgniter's library already made exactly for this job, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter).

Comment: we Need To Use Oauth 2  For Secure API

Comment: I HAve Found This
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/234264/

Comment: which error u getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for integration are in this comment of this answer:

[Integrate oauth 2.0 server with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165015/integrate-oauth-2-0-server-with-codeigniter#comment31861543_21165267)