# Integrate oauth 2.0 server with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I want to integrate a oauth 2.0 server system to access my login externally

I found  CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server in internet but that code seems to be deprecated. It would be a bad idea to integrate it with my codeigniter?

You know of some other project oauth 2.0 server for my codeigniter?

much thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This php server is very good and up to date https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php, and very well documented http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/

You have to do yourself the implementation with codeigniter, but i think that is the best way

For more information take look at : http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: how can compile all php files in my codeigniter? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Almost everything is on this link: http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/ 
You install the server and you create server.php as library codeigniter 
then you just have to create controllers that load the librery server.php

Comment: I'm new to Codeigniter, is there any such existing library which I can use? I have found few but they are not working perfectly and too old.