# CodeIgniter Tank Auth and Social plugins

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, twitter, google-plus

I'm currently working on a new project, using CodeIgniter.

[How should I choose an authentication library for CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter/476902#476902)

The above topic made me chose Tank Auth. But I want my users to be able to login with Facebook, Google or Twitter accounts. So I have 2 possibilities.

1/ integrate them into Tank Auth, as other users started to do here : https://github.com/sicsol/Tank-Auth-Social or here : https://github.com/ericbae/Tank-Auth---3rd-Party-Authentication-Project

2/ I could set the external plugins separately and check if a user is connected through any of the ways I provide.

What solution do you recommend me and why ? Did one of you succesfully integrated that kind of external tools into an existing plugin ? Did you experience some compatibility issues after some new releases of these external resources ? Is this a big problem for a project and so, should I go on and separate things ?

If anyone already did that kind of things even with another framework please provide me your feedback...

Thanks ahead again !