# Codeigniter 3.0 security by methods

Tags: codeigniter, security, codeigniter-3

my doubt is: is there any way to do something like this in codeigniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
     }

  //This method only user with admin permission can access this
  public function onlyAdmin(){
  }
  //This method all user  can access this
  public function allUser(){
  }
}
```

Something like that or more dynamic.

Thanx for you time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is use an authentication library since you'll obviously need authentication at some point in your app. There are a large number available for CodeIgniter each with their own merits and weaknesses in different situations.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter) for a good overview of a few and see if there's one that'll suit your needs.

You'll probably want one that supports different user groups. That way when a user lands on your page you can simply check their group (admin / user / not-logged-in) and then direct them or render the page accordingly. To do this you could use a case statement that runs a different function for each group. These functions should render the page however you need to with the specific customisations for each user group.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do that, but one of basic is [Phill Sturgeon's suggestion](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY/) about having core classes for any of app using level or make something like this (`MY_Controller` class) in your `APPPATH . 'core'` directory:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller // prefix MY_ can be found in APPPATH . 'config/config.php' or you can set your own
{
    public __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Admin_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //pseudo code
        if ($this->session->userdata('level') != 'admin')
        {
            exit("You need admin's privileges to get in here.");
        }
    }
}

class Public_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Than in controllers you would make files/classes that would extend appropriate core class:

```
class Blog extends Public_controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

or something like:

```
class Dashboard extends Admin_controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function some_admin_method()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Alternativelly, you can check [this link](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/) too.