# Codeigniter 3.x Authentication Library?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

With the new Codeigniter 3.0 version what authentication libraries do you use?

- [Flexi auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/) was very good and robust with great documentation for CI 2.0 but it is old and as I can see it is discontinued. Of course it does not work out of the box with CI 3.0. I have tested it and tried to migrate it to CI 3.0 but as it uses the old `ci_sessions` schema I have seen that it has a lot work to be made to rewrite all the code parts that use sessions. It seems to work with file sessions and some alterations on its code though.
- [Community auth](http://community-auth.com/) has a CI 3.0 version but as I have seen, it has many bugs and it is nowhere near reliable at this time. I have tested it thoroughly and it cannot work properly as it has problems with its token jar system and its cookie management. Users cannot login most of the times and it is being used as a whole third-party library at Codeigniter, which personally I don't like as it has a lot of files/folders that are time consuming to be maintained. I would prefer simple CI libraries with 1-2 models like flexi-auth. Although, I wouldn't mind Community Auth's approach if it worked properly.
- [Tank Auth](https://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) was a reliable solution in the past but not with Codeigniter 3.0 as it has many incompatibilities too. [Questions about its compatibility](https://github.com/TankAuth/Tank-Auth/issues/74) with CI 3.0 were asked but no airplanes in the horizon so far.
- [DX Auth](https://github.com/eyoosuf/DX-Auth/issues) is an old authentication library and as I can see on its github repository, there are some [attempts to migrate it](https://github.com/iwatllc/DX-Auth) on CI 3.0 but I haven't been able personally to test any of them.

So, has anyone successfully integrated (or migrated) any of the previous mentioned libraries on large CI 3.0 web applications? Did you write your own? Did you stick with CI 2 until further CI 3.0 development for that matter?

## Update for the down votes

[This post about Authentication libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346980/how-should-i-choose-an-authentication-library-for-codeigniter?rq=1) in codeigniter was very popular and helpful. I believe that posts that help the community in that way should not be closed at least not before some helpful answers. It is not discussed anywhere before and I would really like to see the opinions of more experienced developers for that.

Comment: Now which library works with CodeIgniter 4 ?

Comment: MythAuth is a very good authentication library for CI4
You can find it here: https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth

Answer (score 30, accepted):

don't let the down votes get ya down.

check out Ion Auth 
https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth

take a look at the read me, you will have to rename two files for codeigniter 3. otherwise you can see that there are recent changes to the lib. the author Ben Edmunds is one of the four developers on the new codeigniter council. http://www.codeigniter.com/help/about

Comment: Excellent answer, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

Please check [Dnato System Login](https://github.com/abedputra/CodeIgniter-ion-Auth-Login) 
Its Simple, Fast and Lightweight auth codeigniter.

**Feature:**
-Add user
-Delete user
-Ban, Unban user
-Register new user sent to email token
-Forget password
-Role user level
-Edit user profile
-Gravatar user profile
-Recaptcha by Google
-And much more

**Frontend**
With Bootstrap Framework.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple library, I use https://github.com/trafficinc/CodeIgniter-Authit (Authit).  It is very simple so I can do a lot of customizations to it or just leave it be.

Comment: This isn't a answer, is a comment

Answer (score 1):

check this library.that is so nice.and with many features

- login / logout
- Login DDoS Protection
- register and signup via email. (send verification code to your email)
- users can send private message to other users
- user group
- create permissions and access control
- error in other language

this library for CI2. but if you search about this, you can find lib for CI3

http://codeigniter-aauth-test.readthedocs.io