# Codeigniter database retrieving both in uppercase, lowercase and mixed case

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**my code**

```
// My code:

$this->db->select('*')
->from('tbl_login')
->where(['username'=>$this->input->post('username'),'password'=>$this->input->post('password')]);
$result = $this->db->get()->result();

if($result)
    var_dump($result)
else
    echo "not fount";
```

Doesn't matter what ever I input 'admin1' or 'ADMIN1' & 'password1' or 'PASSWORD1'
it retrieves data from the tables.
But what I actually want is data will be retrieve when case is matched correctly.

Could anyone help???...

Comment: Your database columns are probably defined with case-insensitive collations.  Change their collations to case-sensitive and you should be fine.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not write your own user authentication system, as there are many, many ways to get it dangerously wrong. Using **plain-text passwords** is one such failing. [Codeigniter has many packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311725/codeigniter-3-x-authentication-library) which already work. I'd strongly encourage you to find one that fits your needs, or which is close enough you can adapt it to suit what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**

```
  $query = $this->db->select("*")->from("tbl_login")->where("BINARY username= '".$this->input->post('username')."' and password = '".$this->input->post('password')."'");

  $result = $this->db->get()->result();

   if($result)
      var_dump($result)
   else
      echo "not found";
```

Note: Basically use **BINARY** before your where conditions in Query.

Hope this will help!!