# How I create a login controller? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm having some troubles with codeigniter and the MVC model. In my webpage I have a `main` controller with functions that handles the usual navigation menu with different views `home page,about,support...` but I have a login view.

1. I'm not sure if this separation is correct or I should create a controller for each view.
2. How do I call the login controller, I'm using `base_url('main/myView/');` to call the functions inside the main controller, but if I call the login controller from the login view `base_url('login/foo');` it does not work.

I'm new to codeigniter and I read their tutorial but I still not sure when should I create a new controller.

Thanks

Comment: First read the manual, then look for a tutorial. There are 1000's out there. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: what you want now>

Comment: For starters, create a controller based on your `main controller`. Name the class `'User'`. Then create a function inside it called `'login'`.

Comment: follow this, easy and simple to understand https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to create a multi-controller for each view. you can do it all with one controller.

If you need another controller you can create a new controller and assign it in routes.php. For now, I'm creating 2 controller. Remember controller name start with the capital letter

```
// pages controller
class Pages extends CI_Controller { // `application/controller/Pages.php`
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();     
    }
    public function index(){
        // default_controller
    }
    public function about(){
        // pages/about
    }
    public function support(){
        // pages/support
    }
}

// admin controller
class Admin extends CI_Controller { // `application/controller/Admin.php`
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();     
    }
    public function login(){
        // admin/login
    }
    public function logout(){
        // admin/logout
    }
}
```

Assign url to the controller in `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';   // call lowercase letter
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
$route['support'] = 'pages/support';

$route['login'] = 'admin/login'; // call lowercase letter
$route['logout'] = 'admin/logout';
```

If you call `base_url('login')`, admin controller login function will work

If you call `base_url('about')`, pages controller about function will work

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @downvoter, could you please give me the reason for your down vote. i have given for OP what he needs and he accepted

Answer (score 0):

There are many auth libraries for Codeigniter. I'm sure use the library is better than you write it.

> [Codeigniter 3.x Authentication Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311725/codeigniter-3-x-authentication-library)
>
> https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth
>
> https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-authentication-library

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is for an university project and we need to create our own login system

Comment: No problem mate.