# Array callback must have exactly two elements Error in my login page

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, tankauth

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Array callback must have exactly two elements
>
> Filename:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\admin-template\application\views\auth\login_form.php
>
> Line Number: 85

I'm getting this error while using Tank Auth Library at my password error_form code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <?php echo form_label('Password', $password['id'], ['class' => 'control-label']); ?>
    <?php echo form_password($password, '', 'class="form-control" placeholder="Password"'); ?>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">
      <?php echo form_error($password['name']); ?>
      <?php echo isset($errors[$password['name']]) ? $errors[$password['name']] : ''; ?>
    </small>
    </div>
```

While entering the correct password, I am getting this error. What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: what exactly is line 85? also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311725/codeigniter-3-x-authentication-library (specially the part where they say tank-auth is not ideal for CI 3.0), I personally used Ion Auth for CI 3.x projects